# Quickest way to swap 0 and 1 in a list (not numpy)

Tags: python, list

What is the quickest non-numpy way of swapping 1 and 0 in a Python list?

Comment: Please add an example to make this clear. And how long is the list? Different lengths might have different quickest solutions.

Comment: And does the list only contain zeros and ones, or also other values (if so, what?)?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, it contains only 1s and 0s

Comment: That's an odd list then. You could maybe do what I mentioned in my answer, use a bytearray instead. Lets you do pretty much the same things, plus more, and more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via `bytes`:

```
[*bytes(lst).translate(bytes.maketrans(b'\0\1', b'\1\0'))]
```

Benchmark with [S.B's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77249762/12671057) test case / solutions:

```
 72.4 ± 0.1 μs  [*bytes(lst).translate(trans)]
 72.6 ± 0.1 μs  list(bytes(lst).translate(trans))
 73.0 ± 0.0 μs  [*bytes(lst).translate(bytes.maketrans(b'\0\1', b'\1\0'))]
113.0 ± 0.2 μs  [(1, 0)[i] for i in lst]
126.0 ± 0.6 μs  [0 if i else 1 for i in lst]
130.9 ± 0.4 μs  [1 - i for i in lst]
146.7 ± 1.2 μs  [i ^ 1 for i in lst]
579.6 ± 1.2 μs  [int(not i) for i in lst]
695.3 ± 3.6 μs  [int(not bool(i)) for i in lst]

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

If your program could use a `bytearray` instead of a list, then you could even just use one `translate` call on it, and that would take only ~4 μs.

Benchmark script ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVO9jtRADC7o5iksUWTmlAuJ0KHTSlvxAkiU2YCyuw6MLplEM86K1eqehOYa6Omp6Gh4AJ4Gj5No0f3Aagvbn_PZ_sb-_HU40sfe3d19Gam5vP797Gfj-w7IdmgJbDf0nmZPCRKoJhvI7sKCdli7lON7PKg5FI5BqYA0DrAGnySJagOxWRYp5CkUyz-v4AKKPM8V-doFztgeCUPW1TcoEb1NNvmmSFJgo9jkiVGRTTWj24WFu8zBNmAB24BQQNN7dqwDrlmp0jrSrifY9n2rrTFP4fYhAu8e0hVwye69oI6zmNJW94ELmUezYzIZqK0J9X-HNE9-KhbDLb-B_keG6JQF8nbQJgtDa6m1jrONUs_hde897oj9oPAT7rS8lWF74DDrioe61SJymVdGxamaOJWEVgr45zGM7TnXSHDwUc4FYkwIU2B4gqT82wFxr-JWxTc8NSsoJ-XONW7VHhtZtsDcU0WK2SXFlcFXkk8xP_DG4V4LXdlUplxdVdXcIo2eCZNT3FFNwayusqK5hR_f4CQLK7GXEvv1PUAik76PrKziB9S8m3PxxySQprin6T50w1cQdUzBjd0W_brIDbzg_T4nzz1m9TCg457_knYeQ-hTuMHjWqafy0_qLXqIoLOiyca9kRte8QLx4WUH9MH2zkwXPR_2cuB_AA)):

```py
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys

setup = r'''
lst = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] * 1000
trans = bytes.maketrans(b'\0\1', b'\1\0')
'''

funcs = r'''
[0 if i else 1 for i in lst]
[int(not bool(i)) for i in lst]
[int(not i) for i in lst]
[i ^ 1 for i in lst]
[1 - i for i in lst]
[(1, 0)[i] for i in lst]
[*bytes(lst).translate(bytes.maketrans(b'\0\1', b'\1\0'))]
[*bytes(lst).translate(trans)]
list(bytes(lst).translate(trans))
'''.strip().splitlines()

# Correctness
exec(setup)
expect = eval(funcs[0])
for f in funcs:
    result = eval(f)
    print(result == expect, f)
print()

# Speed
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} μs '
for _ in range(100):
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(f, setup, number=10) / 10
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ways to do so:

```py
from timeit import timeit

lst = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] * 1000

print(
    [0 if i else 1 for i in lst]
    == [int(not bool(i)) for i in lst]
    == [int(not i) for i in lst]
    == [i ^ 1 for i in lst]
    == [1 - i for i in lst]
    == [(1, 0)[i] for i in lst]
)

print(timeit("[0 if i else 1 for i in lst]", globals=globals(), number=1000))
print(timeit("[int(not bool(i)) for i in lst]", globals=globals(), number=1000))
print(timeit("[int(not i) for i in lst]", globals=globals(), number=1000))
print(timeit("[i ^ 1 for i in lst]", globals=globals(), number=1000))
print(timeit("[1 - i for i in lst]", globals=globals(), number=1000))
print(timeit("[(1, 0)[i] for i in lst]", globals=globals(), number=1000))
```

output:

```
True
0.07853270800023893
0.24393120800050383
0.20552908399986336
0.08644929199999751
0.08018908399935754
0.06714641700000357
```